# How to fix $PATH environment on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables

Recently, I tried to install ruby and I somewhat messed up with variable environment. As a result, I am not be able to use paths in .profile or any other path files that I set up before (I tried in .bash_profile, .zschr and etc). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you open a new shell does it have the right path?  Which shell are you using?  I wouldn't expect trying both `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc` to be effective since `bash` and `zsh` are different shells--and (unlikely) possibly neither is the one you're using.  Can you `source` `/etc/profile` and does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you recover your old path, but have a look here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/reset-your-path-variable

A couple of different options are presented to resolve your pickle.

One of the answers suggests `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` is the default so that would be a safe place to start from